# How to make low carb crispy fried cauliflower?

Tags: vegetables, deep-frying, low-carb, keto

Typically I would use a slurry of all purpose flour and cornstarch (with curd/buttermilk) to coat the marinated florets and deep fry them. Resulted in crispy fried cauliflower. An example of a recipe : https://www.kitchenathoskins.com/2017/05/26/crispy-crunchy-buttermilk-fried-cauliflower/#wprm-recipe-container-19056
I need some help in finding out how I can make a low carb version of the same preferably without eggs - am happy to use curd or buttermilk as the slurry base if need be.

Glucomannan is a replacement for cornstarch - but from what I have tried and found it might be a replacement for when cornstarch is used to thicken gravies. I tried coating florets in glucomannan powder, slurry (more like jello) and that did not help in making a crispy end result. And I still need to work my way on finding a low carb APF replacement for frying.

How does one make low carb crispy fried cauliflower?

Comment: What do you consider "low carb".  Is gram flour (chickpea flour) allowed?  If so, look up recipes for gobi pakora.

Comment: @Joe From what I know, chickpea flour is a complex carb and I have used it occasionally as its still relatively carb heavy. Frying florets dipped in a slurry of chickpea flour does not render them crispy. It makes a good pakora - but thats not what I am after.

Comment: possibly of interest : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/99638/67

Comment: how crispy is crispy?  does it need to have a batter coating, or if the florets themselves are crunchy does it work?

Comment: @FuzzyChef Interesting question. Either batter coating or florets themselves will do. I tried to find a measure for crispiness and crunchiness - but am unable to quantify what I am after. This chef had a few videos where he measures in decibels the crispiness upon scratching the floret with a fork - am unable to find it now. To give an idea, just a few seconds around these timestamped links is what I am after : (1) https://youtu.be/F7GVjpBOMMU?t=60 (2 - non-English) https://youtu.be/5brouevnRaE?t=446

Answer (score 2):

When I was low-carbing, I would use almond flour mixed with plenty of seasonings. I also used crushed up pork rinds that I would mix with freshly grated parmesan or the green container parmesan when fresh was not readily available.